# How to validate and parse an UTF-16 encoded XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I am using an UTF-16 encoded XML file. When i tried to validate this file using schema validation, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at    
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.
    createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

My code is given below.

```
SchemaFactor schemaFactory = 
  SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
/** load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance */
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("Sample.xsd"));
try {
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File("Testing.xml")));
    System.out.println("Validation Successs");
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please show your code and a small sample XML file that gives you this error.

Comment: @santro add a small XML sample too please. With special attention to the **beginning** of the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not valid. There is some content before the prolog. XML prolog is generally `<?xml version="1.0"?>` Fix your xml. No problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The content allowed in prolog error is because it's expecting UTF-8...I only was able to fix it by changing my encoding to UTF-8 and then validating.